# Not able to parse json data in flutter

Tags: json, flutter

I am not able to parse below mentioned json data in flutter.

[
{
"id": 96,
"name": "Entertainment",
"link": "https://thehappilyeverafter.in/listing-category/entertainment/",
"image": "https://thehappilyeverafter.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/a685b39b20592b03c0939878edb0cb84.jpg",
"children": [
{
"child_id": 114,
"child_name": "DJs",
"child_link": "https://thehappilyeverafter.in/listing-category/djs/"
},
{
"child_id": 117,
"child_name": "Live Music",
"child_link": "https://thehappilyeverafter.in/listing-category/live-music/"
},
{
"child_id": 115,
"child_name": "Wedding Choreographer",
"child_link": "https://thehappilyeverafter.in/listing-category/wedding-choreographer/"
},
{
"child_id": 116,
"child_name": "Wedding Entertainment",
"child_link": "https://thehappilyeverafter.in/listing-category/wedding-entertainment/"
}
]
}

]`

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Root> rootFromJson(String str) => List<Root>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Root.fromJson(x)));

String rootToJson(List<Root> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));


class Root {
  Root({
    this.id,
    this.name,
    this.link,
    this.image,
    this.children,
  });

  int id;
  String name;
  String link;
  String image;
  List<Children> children;

  factory Root.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Root(
    id: json["id"],
    name: json["name"],
    link: json["link"],
    image: json["image"] == null ? null : json["image"],
    children: List<Children>.from(json["children"].map((x) => Children.fromJson(x))),
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "id": id,
    "name": name,
    "link": link,
    "image": image == null ? null : image,
    "children": List<dynamic>.from(children.map((x) => x.toJson())),
  };
}

class Children {
  Children({
    this.childId,
    this.childName,
    this.childLink,
  });

  int childId;
  String childName;
  String childLink;

  factory Children.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Children(
    childId: json["child_id"],
    childName: json["child_name"],
    childLink: json["child_link"],
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    "child_id": childId,
    "child_name": childName,
    "child_link": childLink,
  };
}
```

[Getting this error][1]
`
type 'List' is not a subtype of type 'Children'

Answer (score 0):

Since your json is a list, you should loop through it:

```dart
final List<Root> roots = yourJson.map((element) {
  return Root.fromJson(element);
}).toList();

print(roots.first.image);
//https://thehappilyeverafter.in/wp-content/uploads/2021/05/a685b39b20592b03c0939878edb0cb84.jpg
```

Comment: I want to loop my children list @Thea Cheng